# Can't catch error

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, error-handling, try-catch

I have a function:

```
buy() {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     this.http.request('http://192.168.1.131:8888/generatetoken.php')
    .subscribe(res => { 
      resolve(res.text());    
    });
   }).then((key) => {
     braintree.dropin.create({
      authorization: key,
      container: '#dropin-container'
    }, (createErr, instance) => {
      if (createErr) {
        // An error in the create call is likely due to
        // incorrect configuration values or network issues.
        // An appropriate error will be shown in the UI.
        console.error(createErr + "      createErrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr");
        return;
      }

        instance.requestPaymentMethod((requestPaymentMethodErr, payload) => {
          if (requestPaymentMethodErr) {
            // No payment method is available.
            // An appropriate error will be shown in the UI.
            console.error(requestPaymentMethodErr + "      reqqe");
            return;
          }

          // Submit payload.nonce to your server
        });

    });
   }).catch(error => console.log(error + "    eoe"));



 }
```

When it runs it outputs this:

`console.error: ERROR [object Object]`

Where can I catch the error? I am catching after the `then()`, but I don't see any other places I can catch. Please help, thanks.

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause of your bug, but one thing to note is that with the `.then(success, failure)` syntax, the failure function **will not** capture errors thrown by the success function. It will only catch errors thrown earlier in the chain.

Comment: thanks, I don't follow completely...are u saying the catch at the end of my code wont catch errors from the `.then()` block? Is there something i can do?

Comment: The `.catch` at the end will capture everything. What I mean is: `.then(() => { throw "error" }, (err) => { // I am never called... }).catch((err) => { // I AM called })` I actually mentioned it because I misread your post. I originally thought you had a two-argument then, but you do not. The `.catch` at the end should be capturing everything.

Comment: so where would the error block that isnt getting called be with respect to my code? how do i catch it?

Comment: Although I am unfamiliar with observables, I also see there is no `reject` path for your original http request, so that error would never be captured by your catch. Additionally, since you do not return the promise created by `braintree.dropin.create`, if it throws an error, it will not be captured by the catch either.

Comment: Ack! Again I spoke too soon. Looking at your code again, it looks like those functions take node style `err, data` callbacks. On second look I actually don't see anywhere this could produce an error that wouldn't be caught, *except* maybe on the initial http request.

Comment: you were right...its happening...the error is `Response with status: 0 for URL` which is CORS related i know what to do to fix it i believe...thank you! post an answer if u want cred!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only place in this code that an error can be thrown is on the initial http request.

Make sure that you have a way to call `reject` if there is an error with that request. From what I know of observables (not much), perhaps this would work:

```
this.http.request('http://192.168.1.131:8888/generatetoken.php')
    .subscribe(
        res => { resolve(res.text()); },
        err => { reject(err); }
    );
```

Comment: thanks - another if you are interested...the result of the error we found - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47046609/response-with-status-0-for-url-likely-cors-issue-angular-http-get-request